# Hadoop fs copy command?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I'm sorry if this is a rather simple question, but I haven't found anything exactly online and just needed a quick answer.

I am trying to copy files from one HDFS directory to a new directory to make a backup. I was given something like this:

```
hadoop fs -mkdir one/two/three/dir1_bkp
hadoop fs -cp one/two/three/dir1/* one/two/three/dir1_bkp
```

This should only copy all of the files in `dir1` to `dir1_bkp` and not affect anything in `dir1`, correct?

Answer (score 1):

Copying doesn't affect the source location, no.

Depending on the size of the data, `distcp` might be a better option

Comment: Thanks. I was told to use `cp` but just some other weird things seemed to be happening to the original but wanted to verify that wasn't from my command.